# Coldfusion Mysql query strange results

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am having either an interesting problem or a brain fart. Not sure which. Is there any reason this query would return different from the coldfusion server than from the actual mysql?

This is part of my query:

```
    <cfquery name="get_team" datasource="bluesky">
    SELECT * FROM locations LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.team_id=locations.location_team        
    WHERE lower(location_name)='#LCASE(a[7])#, #LCASE(a[8])#'
    </cfquery>
    <cfdump var="#get_team#"><cfabort>
```

cfdump results with no information:

```
query
RESULTSET   
query
    COMPANY_ID  LOCATION_CODE   LOCATION_GIFT   LOCATION_ID LOCATION_NAME   LOCATION_TEAM   TEAM_ID TEAM_NAME
CACHED  false
EXECUTIONTIME   1
SQL SELECT * FROM locations LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.team_id=locations.location_team WHERE lower(location_name)='peru, il'
```

Returns this from mysql with the sql above:

```
location_id  location_name  location_gift  location_team  location_code  team_id  team_name  company_id   
85 Peru, IL 11 2 0 2 SJ1 2
```

Comment: check when you generate the query from CF, if it is adding extra space in where clause condition.

Comment: I'm already doing that and you see the results here in the cfdump

        lower(location_name)='peru, il'
Also the bottom results are from running the cfdumped sql statement in mysql via phpmyadmin.

Comment: @user3869579 How did you get the query to run in MySQL?  If you copied and pasted from the cfDump remember that multiple spaces in the source may be rendered as a single space in the browser, so you may have copied and pasted a single space even though multiple are in the source (and being included by CF).  That may be what CFML_Developer meant.

Comment: Thank you, Even though it didnt show any extra spaces using a RTrim and LTrim made it work.

Comment: Fantastic.  It was probably a double space after the comma.  Either you or CFML_Developer should add an answer and mark it as such.  That closes out the question and makes sure credit goes where it is due.

Comment: Don't think it will allow me to do those. I just signed up today. But thank you to both of you for assisting me.

Comment: Don't forget to parameterise that value you're filtering on, rather than hard-coding it into your SQL statement. (and I hope the SELECT * is just for the sake of an expedient example, not your actual code).

Comment: Thanks Adam, this is an import program splitting comma delimited data that has been already sanitized.